# validation for only integers in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when using

```
<input type="number" name="phoneno" class="required number" minlength="10" maxlength="15" id="ph" />
```

it accepts floating point number also. How to use this to prevent the text box to accept other than integers?

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to be trying to get a phone number, not a generic number, you probably want to use the `tel` type of `input`:

```
<input type="tel" name="phoneno" class="required number" maxlength="15" pattern="\d{10}" id="ph" />
```

See [MSDN on `<input>` and its attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input). I’ve removed `minlength`, since it’s not a valid attribute, but the `pattern` attribute’s regex requires 10 characters. You can change that regex if you want to be more flexible in the formats of phone numbers you allow – for instance, you could use `\d{10}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`.

The `pattern` attribute is necessary to actually verify that the text looks like a phone number. The browser does little validation of the contents of `tel` inputs by default; it mainly just displays a keyboard with numbers to mobile browsers. But you can write a JavaScript regular expression in the `pattern` attribute for use in validation (as the MSDN page explains).

Comment: +1 for the most semantic option, deleting my answer in favour of yours

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex object: `^\d+$`
Learn more about regex usage in Javascript [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery solution

html stays at it is

```
<input type="number" name="phoneno" class="required number" minlength="10" maxlength="15" id="ph" />
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function (){$("#ph").blur(function (){
    var regX = /^\d+$/;  
    if(regX.test($(this).val()) == false) 
    {
      //do something it is not int. In this case clear value and alert message 
      $(this).val('');
      alert("put integer");

    }

   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

calling this function on kypress event 
46 is for decimal point just remove it and you are done.

```
    function isNumberKey(evt)
    {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
   if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
     && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
       alert("First Contact Number must be a number(0-9) !");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
    }
```

Comment: isn't it easier to make it on regular expressions?

Comment: to be honest weak RegEx and Variation to the answer...